# Tricks to work with variable names quickly

Tags: python

Good morning. Newby here.

I hope I can frame the question correctly.

I am trying to set up a python template for plotting various hotel variables one by one vs cancellations to see the impact. The data is in a csv file.

So far for every plot I want to make for a specific variable against cancellations I need to manually define the variable throughout the code. This I realize is a timely excercise.

Instead of manually typing in the variable names each time for each plot, how does one go about setting up the template and then defining the variable once to be used throughout the template?

Then for the next plot define the new variable and run the template again.

Hope my question makes sense.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You store the information in a python dictionary, in the template that you want.

Comment: Write a function?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're looking for a dictionary.

`hotels = {"hotel1": "not cancelled", "hotel2": "cancelled"}`

This way you'll be able to access each key and get the value, which could be much more complicated than "cancelled" or "not cancelled", they could even be dicts themselves.

`hotels = {"hotel1": {"cancellations": 4, "reservations" 10}....}`

loop over your dictionary using

```
for hotel in hotels:
  print(hotels[hotel]["cancellations"])
```